# Split multiple strings in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I am trying to split multiple columns of strings at the same time.

My original data looks like:

Table1

| UserID | Type | ProductID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B | 001, 003 |

and I want to end up with

| UserID | Type | ProductID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 001 |
| 1 | B | 003 |

When I use

```
select *
from Table1
cross apply string_split(Type, ',')
cross apply string_split(ProductID, ',')
```

I end up with this table that I do not want...

| UserID | Type | ProductID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 001 |
| 1 | B | 003 |
| 1 | A | 003 |
| 1 | B | 001 |

How do I split multiple columns of strings simultaneously?

Comment: You need a splitting function that preserves order and provides it as a part of the resultset it generates. STRING_SPLIT does not do either of those - guarantee order or provide a value that determines order.  Simple searching will find such functions and solutions. Better yet - normalize your schema.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? (`SELECT @@VERSION;`, not Help > About in SSMS) Also, what do you expect to happen if Type and Product have a different number of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2016 and above, you can use `OPENJSON` to split strings with deterministic ordering. Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1
(
   UserID int, 
   Type varchar(255), 
   ProductID varchar(255)
);

INSERT dbo.Table1(UserID, Type, ProductID)
VALUES(1, 'A, B', '001, 003');
```

You can use this query:

```
SELECT t.UserID, [Type] = LTRIM(j1.value), Product = LTRIM(j2.value)
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON
  (CONCAT('["',REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(Type, 'json'),',','","'),'"]')
) AS j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON
  (CONCAT('["',REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(ProductID, 'json'),',','","'),'"]')
) AS j2
WHERE j1.[key] = j2.[key];
```

Which produces this output:

| UserID | Type | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 001 |
| 1 | B | 003 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fee31581957898db695620049d08e279)

Comment: Considering they are strings, I would add string_escape() just to be safe  +1

Answer (score 0):

you can use `STRING_SPLIT` *for split strings*,`row_number` *for create ID  in join* and `subquery` *for join* as follows

```
select a.UserID,Type1,ProductID from 
(SELECT 
    UserID,value Type1 ,row_number() over (order by   value asc) rn
FROM Table1 
  cross apply  STRING_SPLIT(Type, ',')) a
  JOIN /*subquery*/
(SELECT 
    UserID,value ProductID,row_number() over (order by   value asc)   rn
FROM Table1
  cross apply  STRING_SPLIT(ProductID, ',')) b
  on a.rn=b.rn
  order by ProductID desc
```

Comment: @belle Are the values in the substrings always going to be in alphabetical order? While `String_Split` does not guarantee the order of results, this answer uses `order by value` to _fix_ the data.